# Android - Swipe refresh on active fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

[image: MainActivity]

I have a fragment inside the MainActivity

on the menu, there is a refresh button and swipe refresh option which calls myUpdateOperation() method

This fragment may be different according to user's selection.

How can I make sure the right fragment currently active gets refreshed when the refresh action is invoked?

> content_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.app.main_fragment.MainFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");

                    // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
                    // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
                    myUpdateOperation();
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
    );
}

void myUpdateOperation(){
    // TODO: 20-Mar-17
    Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

> Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }

    public void fragment1refresh(){
        // TODO: this to be call when refresh on MainActivity and also fragment_1 is visible 
    }

}
```

> Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


    public Fragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
    }

    public void fragment2refresh(){
        // TODO: this to be call when refresh on MainActivity and also fragment_2 is visible 
    }

}
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me, why this post got downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this make your `Fragment1` and `Fragment2` class extends `CustomFragment`
The code for `CustomFragment` can be something like this

```
public abstarct class CustomFragment extends Fragment {

        public CustomFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public abstract void refresh();
}
```

Change `Fragment1` implementation to:

```
public class Fragment1 extends CustomFragment {


        public Fragment1() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void refresh(){
            // TODO: this to be call when refresh on MainActivity and also fragment_1 is visible 
        }
}
```

Similarly change the implementation of `Fragment2` class.

Now in your `MainActivity` class get a reference to current visible fragment. This can be done as:

```
CustomFragment currentFragment = (CustomFragment)mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
```

Now inside change `myUpdateOperation()` implementation to :

```
private void myUpdateOperation(){
// TODO: 20-Mar-17
currentFragment.refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current fragment from the fragment manager, then check which fragment type matches with it:

```
Fragment currentFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
if (currentFragment instanceof Fragment1) {
    ((Fragemnt1) currentFragment).fragment1refresh()
} if (currentFragment instanceof Fragment2) {
    ((Fragemnt2) currentFragment).fragment2refresh()
}
```